# How to combine Asp.Net Identity with Azure AD Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How to integrate Asp.Net Identity with Azure AD Authorization

Is it possible to integrate Asp.Net Identity with Azure AD Authorization by means of OpenIdConnect? I'd like to have a both authorization providers one for local authorization ( by means of standart Asp.net core Identity and second by means of Azure AD

```
        _services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                options.Authority = $"{baseAuthorityUrl}/{tenantId}/v2.0";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString(callBackPath);
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };
            })
```

This works for Azure AD Authorization, but i can't change authorization method from Azure AD to ASp.Net Identity. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using the default ASP.NET Identity template to start the project :

1. Create new application with ASP.NET Identity (Individual User Accounts template).
2. Seed the database with Migrations `Add-Migration Name` , `Update-Database` .
3. Add your OIDC provider :

   ```
   services
   .AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

   }).AddCookie()
   .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
   {

       options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

       options.ClientId = ClientId;
       options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
       options.Authority = $"{baseAuthorityUrl}/{tenantId}/v2.0";
       options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
       options.Scope.Add("email");
       options.Scope.Add("profile");
       options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

       options.SaveTokens = true;
       options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           NameClaimType = "name"
       };

   });
   ```

Make sure using `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` for SignInScheme otherwise the Identity won't accept external login information correctly .

Asp.net will create a local account that associates your external account , so that you can perform authorization with your local identity system .